# How to obtain serviceTime in Sink?

Tags: omnet++

I need to use the serviceTime on simulation in Sink when handling the message. How can I recover it? I was trying different ways, but didn't work. For example, to recover in the same way that the server component retrieve the value, but I am getting error:
Sink.h

```
Job *jobServiced;
```

Sink.cc

```
void Sink::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
jobServiced = check_and_cast<Job *>(msg);
simtime_t serviceTime = par("serviceTime");
```

Before I have tried this option, but I didn't obtain the correct values to get the mean of the service Time and service rate:

sink.cc

```
void Sink::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    num_jobs++;
    serviceTime = (serviceTime + job->getTotalServiceTime())/num_jobs;
    serviceRate= (1/serviceTime);
}
void Sink::finish()
{       recordScalar("ServiceTime", serviceTime);
       recordScalar("ServiceRate", serviceRate);
}
```

I am getting:

```
Service Time      Service Rate   
0.50                 1.99
0.43                 2.29
0.25                 3.99
0.11                 8.49
0.10                 9.38
0.05                 17.815
0.13                 7.403
0.003                30.485
```

In the runs, there is a point that I get an error cannot convert 1.0336e+007 to simtime_t: out of the range (-922337203685477) allowed by scale exponent -12.

Thank you

...

Comment: Ohh. Please DON'T do this. StackOverflow is a Q&A site. It is not a forum where you discuss things freely. You have fundamentally changed your original question and added a totally new problem to it. It is NOT possible to have a correct answer to such a question and the provided (correct) answers will become INVALID. This will be totally useless for future readers. If the answer solved your problem ACCEPT it and form your new question in a separate question.

Comment: Sorry about that, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Sink.cc:

```
void Sink::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    Job *job = check_and_cast<Job *>(msg);

    // gather statistics
    emit(lifeTimeSignal, simTime()- job->getCreationTime());
    emit(totalQueueingTimeSignal, job->getTotalQueueingTime());
    emit(queuesVisitedSignal, job->getQueueCount());
    emit(totalServiceTimeSignal, job->getTotalServiceTime());
    emit(totalDelayTimeSignal, job->getTotalDelayTime());
    emit(delaysVisitedSignal, job->getDelayCount());
    emit(generationSignal, job->getGeneration());

    if (!keepJobs)
        delete msg;
}
```

That's how all accumulated statistics in the job can be accessed. i.e. use:

```
job->getTotalServiceTime()
```

Comment: Thank you Rudi, I have defined in omnet.ini: **.serviceTime = exponential(0.4s). The mean recovered for totalServiceTimeSignal is about 0.4. However, when collecting the totalServiceTime value and dividing by the number of jobs, I am not getting the same results. The run finishes with the error:"simtime_t:out of range allowed by scale exponent -12. 
Do I have to add or substract something to obtain the ServiceTime by job?

Comment: There is some misunderstanding here regarding what totalServiceTime. totalServiceTime statistic accumulates the service time as the job travels in the network an arrives to different Servers. I.e. EACH job has its sepaarte totalServiceTime variable and that value contains the TOTAL time THAT job sent in ANY of the Servers in the network. It makes absolutely no sense to divide the totalServiceTime with the number of jobs.